# React preloading components with Lazy + Suspense

Tags: reactjs, preload, dynamic-import, react-16

I'm currently using React 16 with Suspense and Lazy to code-split my codebase. Although I would like to preload components.

In my example below I got two routes. Is there a way to preload `Demo` as soon `Prime` did mount? I've tried to create another dynamic import in the `componentDidMount` of the `Prime` page, but `React.lazy` doesn't seem to get that that's the same file as the dynamic import below.

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import GlobalStyle from 'styles';

import Loading from 'common/Loading';
const Prime = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Prime" */'modules/Prime'));
const Demo = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Demo" */'modules/Demo'));

const App = () => (
  <main>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading>Loading...</Loading>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Prime} exact />
        <Route path="/demo" component={Demo} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </main>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

So I've tried different approaches, for example with and without `webpackChunkName` and different ways of importing the other component in `componentDidMount`, as seen below. The first two approaches of importing the file in `componentDidMount` resulted in a Webpack error shown at the bottom of the image below. Only the third proceeded, but made the file `2.[hash].js` in the image, only load after the page was visited, and not on `componentDidMount`

[image]

What am I missing here?

Code of `modules/Demo.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

import LogoIcon from 'vectors/logo.svg';
import PageLink from 'common/PageLink';
import Anchor from 'common/Anchor';
import CenteredSection from 'common/CenteredSection';

const Demo = () => (
  <CenteredSection variant="green">
    <LogoIcon />
    <PageLink to="/" variant="green">Go to home page</PageLink>
  </CenteredSection>
);

export default Demo;
```

Comment: Using `lazy` within componentDidMount of Prime won't do you any good for the preload case since it causes the component to be loaded when it is rendered. Approaches 2 and 3 seem fine at first glance, but the error you're getting for 1 and 2 makes me want to see the code for `modules/Demo` since it seems that something is causing a cyclic dependency.

Comment: @RyanC thanks for your response. I've added the code of the Demo page. You can also view to codebase over here: https://github.com/JBostelaar/react-prime/tree/progressive-web-app/src

I also thought the first approach couldn't work, but still I wanted to show what I've tried. 2 gives the error, 3 doesn't preload the page.

Comment: The code structure is a little different than I was expecting. I was expecting to see `modules/Demo.jsx` and `modules/Prime.jsx`. I'm not saying that what you have is "wrong", but having `Demo/index.jsx` instead just deviates from approaches that I have used that I can give more confident direction on.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I’m pretty sure that the issue doesn’t come from my folder structure or naming.

Comment: Nice webpackChunkName usage. Didn't know you could name your chunks that way, thanks ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is incredibly easy to do, I think there is a misunderstanding about what lazy() and Suspense are doing under the hood.

The only expectation that React.lazy() has is that it takes a function that returns a Promise that resolves with a default component.

```js
React.lazy(() => Promise<{default: MyComponent}>)
```

So if you want to preload, all you have to do is execute the promise yourself ahead of time.

```js
// So change this, which will NOT preload
import React from 'react';
const MyLazyComp = React.lazy(() => import('./path/to/component'));

/*********************************************/

// To this, which WILL preload
import React from 'react';

// kicks off immediately when the current file is imported
const componentPromise = import('./path/to/component');

// by the time this gets rendered, your component is probably already loaded
// Suspense still works exactly the same with this.
const MyLazyComp = React.lazy(() => componentPromise);
```

The fact that this is a known signature makes it for useful for all sorts of other situations. For instance, I have a bunch of components that rely on the google maps api being dynamically loaded, I was able to create a function that loads the google maps api and then imports the component. I won't detail the internals of this example since it's a tangent, but the point is I made myself a function that does a bunch of async stuff and then returns a Promise with an object of {default: Component}.

```
import React from 'react';
const MyLazyComp = React.lazy(() => importMapsComponent('./path/to/comp'));
```

Comment: But with this change it will just simply load the lazy import file on Application load, so what's the use of Lazy here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much help this will be, but here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5x3zn9ywn4) that works (Demo gets loaded by componentDidMount). It is a considerably simplified version of your code using create-react-app for the config. Perhaps you can take this as a starting point and morph it gradually closer to your app to see what causes the dynamic import to no longer work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was further complicated by a separation between the lazy and the component that needed to initiate preloading.

I found you can simply use a line like:

```js
void (async () => import('the-lazy-import'))();
```

to preload the import, even without having access to the lazy component.